# Recurrence relations :rate of growth

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider the multiplication of bacteria in a controlled environment. Let ar
denote the number of bacteria there are on the r-th day. We denote the rate of growth on the r-th day to be ar- 2(ar- 1). If it is known that the rate of growth doubles every day, determine ar, given that a0= 1

The recurrence formed is $a_{r+1}-4a_{r}+4a_{r-1}=0$

solution is $a_{r}=c*2^r+d*r2^r$ 
by $a_{0}=1 \implies c=1$ 
but how to calculate $d$?

Comment: If the rate of growth doubles every day, would itn't be $d=0$ ?

Comment: It is curious to denote the rate of growth as $a_r-2a_{r-1}$.  The factor $2$ is strange.  Accepting that, shouldn't the recurrence be $a_r=2a_{r-1}+b2^{r-1}$ where $b$ is the rate of growth on day 1?  We don't have enough information to calculate $a_1$.  We need $b$

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{r \ge 0} a_r z^r$, rewrite your recurrence without subtraction in indices:
$$
a_{r + 1} - 4 a_{r + 1} + 4 a_r = 0
$$
Multiply by $z^r$, sum over $r \ge 0$, and recognize the resulting sums:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}
  - 4 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
  + 4 A(z)
  = 0
$$
Solve for $A(z9$, write as partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = \frac{4 a_0 - a_1}{2 (1 - 2 z)} - \frac{2 a_0 - a_1}{2 (1 - 2 z)^2}
$$
By the generalized binomial theorem:
\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{4 a_0 - a_1}{2} \cdot 2^n
         + \frac{2 a_0 - a_1}{2} \cdot \binom{-2}{n} (-2)^n \\
    &= \left(
         \frac{4 a_0 - a_1}{2}
           + \frac{2 a_0 - a_1}{2} \cdot \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1}
       \right) \cdot 2^n \\
    &= ((2 a_0 - a_1) n + 6 a_0 - 2 a_1) \cdot 2^{n - 1}
\end{align}